# How to define and code custom unit-test in raw PHP?

Tags: php, testing, frameworks

I am using some special PHP framework. I can't use any unit-test frameworks by some reasons like PHPunit or codeception. So i need to write my custom code to achieve that. Is there any examples could finish the job?

Can i use this method instead of using framework?

```
    public function testFailure()
    {
       $a = 1; $b = 0;
       if($a !=== b){
          //throw exception here
       }
    }
```

Instead-

```
    public function testFailure()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 0); //return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolutely easiest way would be pretty much what you wrote above (although the code is not really valid). Throw an exception on assertions and you have a valid way of unit testing!

Now, I would think that you could probably use something like phpunit weather or not you are using some custom code, but I won't push on that more than letting you know.

Also:

`!===` is invalid, `!==` would be more correct!

---

Further on, I'd recommend that you create some type of static or global methods for your `assertions` instead of the above, that way you can easily re-use the exception throwing code instead of writing the same over and over:

```
// assert.php
class Assert {
  public static function isEqual($a, $b) {
    if ($a != $b) {
      throw new MyAssertionException('Not equal!');
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static function isSame($a, $b) {
    if ($a !== $b) {
      throw new MyAssertionException('Not same!');
    }
    return true;
  }

}

---

// test.php
include_once 'assert.php';

Assert::isEqual(1, 2);
```